# Shell code doesn`t run in XP environment if processing many files

Tags: excel, vba, wsh, windows-scripting

This VBA code I wrote runs in Windows 7 but not in XP.

```
Public Function WShellRun(command As String)

    Dim wShell As Object
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 0

    Dim errorCode As Integer

    Dim wExec, rslt As String

    Set wShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    wShell.CurrentDirectory = ActiveWorkbook.Path

    On Error GoTo WinXpMode

    errorCode = wShell.Run(command, windowStyle, waitOnReturn)

    If errorCode <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "SHELL COULDN`T STARTED " & errorCode, vbCritical, "SHELL ERROR"
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set wShell = Nothing

    Exit Function

WinXpMode:

    Set wExec = wShell.Exec("%ComSpec% /c " & command)    ''(1) execute DOS

    Do While wExec.Status = 0                       ''(2) wait until response
        DoEvents
    Loop

    'rslt = wExec.StdOut.ReadAll                   ''(3) show result

    'MsgBox rslt

    Set wExec = Nothing
    Set wShell = Nothing

End Function
```

I thought WSH doesn't run on XP so I wrote a GOTO to which the code would flow when something happened to the script. But when I run it in XP environment, the WinXPMode part and the upper part runs parallel that it freezes the flow of the program (I think).

I have two questions.

1. Is there any way to upgrade the code to work in both Windows 7 and XP so I don't have to worry about the environment.
2. Is there any way to check what is wrong with the code or the system?

I found that when I run the .jar for few files (10 or 20 file names), it goes without any problem. After that I tried for many files like 100 file names. Then it showed me an error that it can't output file (can't write file), which doesn't show up in Windows 7.

Comment: does it work if `command` is "notepad.exe" (change `windowStyle = 1`)? Also usually this should be a Sub, Function is meant to return something at the end. what is the content of the `command`?

Comment: @PatricK command is like "java -jar jcompressor.jar " & fileName & " -o " & fileName & " --charset utf8"

Comment: "notepad.exe"s are good. Why i used wsh was i call this jar file several times that i need to sync it with the program.

Comment: Where ever you have `Function`, change it to `Sub` and then step through the code. Now see which line gives you the error or which line does the code actually freeze

Comment: Ok, sounds like XP does not have a Environment variable to launch `java.exe`? In XP, launch command prompt and type `java` and hit Enter, does it show usage? If not, than it is missing the path to java.exe and hence nothing is executed.

Comment: You need to add an environmental variable for java :)

Comment: @PatricK @Siddharth Rout. Thanks for answering. I changed the Function into Sub, then i checked the java. Neither of them has succeeded.Actually i`ve been debugging all day.And I just found out that when run the .jar for few files(10 or 20 file names),it goes without any problem. After that i tried for many files like 100 file names. Then it showed me an error that can`t output file (can`t write file) , which doesn`t show up in Windows 7.

Comment: @mehow i believe the java settings are fine.